# Variable assignment to JavaScript from a view in ASP.NET MVC for CanvasJS chart

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, charts, canvasjs

I'm just a beginner in ASP.NET and JavaScript, so thank you for taking time to help me and be specific.
I'm trying to plot a chart using CanvasJS in ASP.NET MVC and have created a variable where I put all the data I want to render in a form which the script is using to get that data.

My variable:

```
datatest = {y:0 , label:"" }, {y:5, label:"Vrai"}, {y:1, label:"Faux"}
```

The problem is that I couldn't make the script read this variable, so it can't plot the chart according the data I provided.

However, when I enter manually the data in the same form to script, it works perfectly.

I'm using:

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
  src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
```

I tried using `@datatest` to call the variable, but it didn't work, I also tried   `<input id="testingid" type="hidden" value="@datatest" />` and it didn't work neither.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            var test2 =  document.getElementById('testingid').value;
```

When I enter manually the data in the same form to script, it works perfectly.

All the code you see here is on my view:

```
var datatest = "{y:0 , label:\"\" }";
      foreach (var itemopt in Model.Where(c => c.QuestionsID == item.ID))
          {
             <tr>
                <td > @itemopt.Name</td>
                <td >@itemopt.Expr1</td>
                <td ></td>
            </tr>

        datatest = datatest + ", {y:" + @itemopt.Expr1 + ", label:\"" + 
                   @itemopt.Name + "\"}";  
        /* {y:0 , label:"" }, {y:5, label:"Vrai"}, {y:1, label:"Faux"}*/
            }
            <input id="testingid" type="hidden" value="@datatest" />

                            /* CHART PLOTING */

        <div id="chartContainer" style="height: 150px; width: 50%;"></div>

            <script type="text/javascript">

                var test2 =  document.getElementById('testingid').value;

                window.onload = function () {
                    var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
                        theme: "light2",
                        animationEnabled: true,
                        title: {
                            text:"Column Chart in ASP.Net MVC using CanvasJS"
                               },
                        data: [
                            {
                                type: "column",
                                dataPoints: [test2]
                            }
                               ]
       });
       chart.render();
       };
       </script>
```

I don't get any error, I just don't get the chart displayed. It's like I don't have any data.

What am I doing wrong? Could you please advise me?